# Duration between two times in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 5 fields in one of my mysql tables. 3 of them are date, time1 and time2. date is DATE data type and time1 and time2 are TIME data type. I want to calculate the interval between time1 and time2, and display in the internet browser. I tried as follows in PHP,but it didn't work.

```
$start_time = strtotime($row['time1']);
$end_time = strtotime($row['time2']);
$interval = $end_time - $start_time;
```

Do I have to combine date and time in one field and store as timestamp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try somethig like this:

```
   $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);   
    $interval->format($differenceFormat);
```

reff :http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  $date_1 must be a timestamp? It cant be like "08:44:45" isnt it? so i have to combine both date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this using DateTime class

```
$date_time1 = new DateTime('09:00:59');
$date_time2 = new DateTime('09:01:00');
$interval = $date_time1->diff($date_time2);
$interval->format('%s seconds(s)');
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$start_time = strtotime($row['time1']);
$end_time = strtotime($row['time2']);
$ts1 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $start_time));
$ts2 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $end_time));
$diff = abs($ts1 - $ts2) / 3600;
```